# cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget

Tags: iphone, performselector

cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget is not working for me, i checked every one saying its working fine but for me not

i call the following in performselector

```
[self performSelector:@selector(Opacity:) withObject:self.objopcarray afterDelay:reversedelay];
```

now i want to cancel it on a button click before it fires so i did the following

```
- (void) pressNextButton:(id)sender
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(Opacity:) object:self.objopcarray];

    if (self.animationON == YES)
    {
        if (self.panel < 16) 
        {
            [self DisplayImages];
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:sketchanimduration target:self selector:@selector(DisplayImages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

            if(self.panel > 16)
            {
                self.panel = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but still same result

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: in above code this line is not working

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(Opacity:) object:self.objopcarray];

Comment: Are `perform..` and `cancel..` method call on different threads???? Like perfrom.. in background thread and obviously pressNextButton on main thread ?

Comment: No i used performSelector which i think run on the main thread so what i need to do ?

Comment: if it is on main thread then..it should work... as button action will  also run on main thread...